# Creating ggplot scale breaks for different objects when called within R function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this sample data:

```
df <- tibble(
 "PLAYER" = c("Corey Kluber", "CLayton Kershaw", "Max Scherzer", "Chris Sale",
   "Corey Kluber", "Jake Arrieta", "Jose Urena", "Yu Darvish"),
 "YEAR" = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017),
 "WHIP" = c(1.24, 1.50, 1.70, 1.35, 1.42, 1.33, 1.61, 1.10),
 "ERA" =  c(3.27, 4.0, 2.56, 1.45, 3.87, 4.23, 3.92, 2.0)
 )
```

And this function:

```
baseball_stats <- function(player, statistic) {

  # Libraries
  library(tidyverse)

  # Function to set scale to number of seasons played by pitcher &
  # appropriate scale for chosen statistic
  f <- function(k) {
    step <- k
    function(y) seq(floor(min(y)), ceiling(max(y)), by = step)
  }

  # ggplot of player and chosen statistic
  p <- df %>% 
    group_by(PLAYER) %>% 
    filter(PLAYER == player) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes_string("YEAR", statistic), width = .5) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = f(1)) +  # Uses the function to set YEAR breaks
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = f(0.25)) + # Would like to set this so it changes for whatever stat is chosen
    theme_bw()

}

# Function call, with chosen statistic
baseball_stats("Corey Kluber", "ERA")
```

The `df` has two separate statistics, WHIP & ERA. But, each of these statistics requires a different scale. The function before the `ggplot` code helps set the scale.

I would like to be able to code something where the scale for `WHIP` can equal `0.1`, and the scale for `ERA` can equal `0.25`, and the function would pick up on that for whatever statistic is chosen in the argument. I hope that makes sense. Thank ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your function `f` and wrapped it around the function `ticks`that is just an if/else if to pick up on the statistic. You can keep extending the if/else if you add more stats to your dataset

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  "PLAYER" = c("Corey Kluber", "CLayton Kershaw", "Max Scherzer", "Chris Sale",
               "Corey Kluber", "Jake Arrieta", "Jose Urena", "Yu Darvish"),
  "YEAR" = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017),
  "WHIP" = c(1.24, 1.50, 1.70, 1.35, 1.42, 1.33, 1.61, 1.10),
  "ERA" =  c(3.27, 4.0, 2.56, 1.45, 3.87, 4.23, 3.92, 2.0)
)

baseball_stats <- function(player, statistic) {

  # Function to set scale to number of seasons played by pitcher &
  # appropriate scale for chosen statistic

  f <- function(step) {
    function(y) seq(floor(min(y)), ceiling(max(y)), by = step)
  }

  ticks <- function(stat) {
    if (stat == "WHIP") {
      step <- 0.1
    } else if (stat == "ERA") {
      step <- 0.25
    }
    return(f(step))
  }

  # ggplot of player and chosen statistic
  p <- df %>% 
    group_by(PLAYER) %>% 
    filter(PLAYER == player) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes_string("YEAR", statistic), width = .5) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = f(1)) +  # Uses the function to set YEAR breaks
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = ticks(statistic)) + # Would like to set this so it changes for whatever stat is chosen
    theme_bw()

}

# Function call, with chosen statistic
lol <- baseball_stats("Corey Kluber", "ERA")
```

Edit: use switch instead of if else

```r
ticks <- function(stat) {
  switch (stat,
    WHIP = {step <- 0.1},
    ERA = {step <- 0.25}
  )
  return(f(step))
}
```

Comment: This is unreal! Do I just `else if` again and again, when adding new stats?

Comment: Absolutely! However, at that point you might want to use a switch instead. See my edit